# How to simulate two-dimensional collision on Manim?

Tags: python, physics, manim

I am trying to simulate a scenario of relativistic momentum using Manim library. I need two circular objects to collide and move apart in directions opposite to their initial direction of travel. However, I am unable to make my circles collide. They move right past each other. I have attached my code. Could anyone please guide about how to do this on Manim?

```
def construct(self):
    ax = Axes().add_coordinates()
    def func(x):
        return x+1

    def func1(x):
        return -x+1

    t = ValueTracker(-5)
    circle = Circle(color=YELLOW)
    circle.add_updater(
            lambda x: x.move_to(ax.c2p(func(t.get_value()),0.5)
            ).set_color(YELLOW))

    t1 = ValueTracker(0)
    circletwo = Circle(color=RED)
    circletwo.add_updater(
            lambda x: x.move_to(ax.c2p(func1(t1.get_value()), 0.5)
                                ).set_color(RED))
    #Bounce off each other
    if circletwo.get_left()[0] <= circle.get_right()[0] or circle.get_right()[0] >= circletwo.get_left()[0]:
        circle.add_updater(lambda x: x.move_to(ax.c2p(func1(t.get_value()), 0.5)
                            ).set_color(YELLOW))

        circletwo.add_updater(lambda x: x.move_to(ax.c2p(func(t.get_value()), 0.5)
                            ).set_color(YELLOW))
    
    self.add(circle, circletwo)
    self.play(t.animate.set_value(2), t1.animate.set_value(5), run_time=6)
```

Comment: Which version of Manim are you using? Please show the code for the class that your construct method is part of as well as how you are running it. [Here is a Quickstart guide](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/quickstart.html).

Comment: Hey, I am using the community edition of Manim. I am running it on cmd using manim -pql filename.py classname. This is my starting code. 
 from manim import *

class RelativisticCollision(Scene):
    def construct(self):